# make custom cell 100% transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, custom-cell

I am trying to build a table with custom header and custom cells. 
I would like to create an illusion of spaces between my cells. For that I want to make cell background transparent and add image inside cell which will be smaller than cell 5pt from each side.

Is it possible? I was trying to change alpha to 0 in my Attribute inspector for element cell but it doesn't help.

Also in my cell for identifier method i was trying to use

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
```

But it didn't help.

Can anybody suggest on this?

*** UPDATE1 ***

I figured out the issue.

My code was actually good. Nazmul Hasan proposed also working code. In this case my and his solution are working the same.

I have changed background property from white to Clear Color ...  not for cell item but for Table view one.

After that cell became transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this way

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: This won't make any difference, a color with alpha = 0 is transparent, no matter what the other components are.

Comment: @Sven you are right! I have updated my question. the issue was in background property for table view